# How to write the complete output of multi line strings in a text file using python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have the following text file containing the strings in the manner given below

```
trymf_001/trymrf_001_001
trymf_001/trymf_001_002
...
trymf_001/trymf_001_160
...
trymt_018/trymt_018_280
```

With the following code,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
fo = open ("stt.text", "r")
for line in fo.readlines():
    a = line.find('/')
    str1 = line[0:9]
    str2 = line[10:23]
    y = str2 + ' ' + str1
    print(y)
fo = open ("newstt.text", "w")
fo.write(y)
fo.close()
```

the output I get on the terminal screen when I print is:

```
trymrf_001_001 trymf_001
trymrf_001_002 trymf_001
...
trymf_001_160 trymf_001
...
trymt_018_280 trymt_018
```

But, I am getting only one line (the last one) in the new text file, while I 
need all the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last line gets written because you are defining `y` inside the `for` loop which means on every iteration `y` gets redefined. You can try this instead

```
 fo = open ("stt.text", "r")
 y_list = [] # make new list to store all the data
 for line in fo.readlines():
     a = line.find('/')
     str1 = line[0:9]
     str2 = line[10:23]
     y = str2 + ' ' + str1
     y_list.append(y) # store all the data to the newly created list
     print(y)
 fo.close()
 fo = open ("newstt.text", "w")
 for lines in y_list:
     fo.write(lines+"\n") # write all the data from the list
 fo.close()
```

Comment: Collecting everything into memory before you write it out will fail once the input file is big enough.  For this reason, the other answer is preferrable.  (Of course, if the lines were hideously long, you still end up consuming a lot of memory; there's a separate fix for that, but let's not go there until you actually have that problem.)

Comment: Kindly, suggest me that way of doing in the above code,because my file is big enough.

Comment: what exactly do you want

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as You read it. Now, You're reading all of them, and writing only last one. It should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
fi = open ("stt.text", "r")
fo = open ("newstt.text", "w")
for line in fi.readlines():
    a = line.find('/')
    str1 = line[0:9]
    str2 = line[10:23]
    y = str2 + ' ' + str1
    print(y)        
    fo.write(y)
fo.close
```

Comment: You should use `with` to open the files: `with open('a', 'r') as fi, open('b', 'w') as fo:`